# Convert Character Between UTF-8 to ANSI (windows 1252) on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, vscode-extensions, cp1252

Does anyone know how to directly convert UTF-8 characters in a file to ANSI (Windows 1252) right on Visual Code without having to use another application?

My problem was that I was using the default Windows1252 setting when opening .txt files (Because my files are encoded in ANSI).

[image: Current Version VSCode]
[image: Current Setting for ANSI (Windows 1252)]

After I enter UTF-8 characters. I want to convert these characters to ANSI encoding (Windows1252). See a photo of the UTF8 characters I entered.
[image: Entered UTF8 Character]

Currently I'm struggling with the Notepad++ application, Copying text from VSCode, then pasting into Notepad++ with UTF-8, then converting to ANSI. And I copied it back to VsCode. This is driving me and a lot of other people crazy.

I am currently using an Extension "Vscode Google Translate" at: [Link Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=funkyremi.vscode-google-translate), I highlight the text and then press the shortcut it translates the language. So I hope everyone knows which Extension has the feature to convert UTF-8 to Windows1252. That's really helpful.

I tried to search for the keywords: How to convert UTF-8 to ANSI on VSCode, How to convert UTF-8 to Windows1252 on VSCode, Extension Convert UTF-8 to ANSI VSCode... etc..

But I didn't find any results or answers that I wanted.

So I look forward to everyone's understanding.

Comment: There's an encoding switch in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: I don't think the current version of VSCode on my machine has that Switch. I'm still figuring out why I don't have that switch. Thank you very much for your reply. See photos without switches. [link](https://imageupload.io/ib/c7e7ywxdevRmcU6_1697384304.png)

Comment: the switch is the encoding in the status bar, hover your mouse and you see it turns into a button

Comment: Right click the status bar, maybe you disabled it.

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you very much. Normally I don't use the Status Bar. Once I have opened the file, I then enable the Status Bar. I don't see these Switches. I closed the file and opened it again. These switches have appeared. This converts my entire file to UTF-8 encoding, Then I convert it all back to ANSI. It's also not an effective way. Hopefully in the future someone will develop an extension to convert only highlighted characters without having to convert the entire file.

Comment: I think that will never happen because you have to descramble the incorrect decoded characters, UTF-8 is varying multi byte. The strings in VSC memory are Unicode points, the en/de-coding is only used from/to files.

Comment: There is something wrong with Windows1252/ISO 8859-1 encoding on VSCode.
I have a file (Understood as ANSI when opening it on Notepad++ version 8.5.7, So I do the transcoding to UTF-8 and enter the UTF-8 characters, then I do the save without having to converted back to ANSI, UTF-8 characters still displayed fine in my game without any problems).
But if I open this file on VSCode with Windows1252 or utf-8 encoding, I enter text containing UTF-8 characters and do a save with Windows1252 or ISO88591 or Windows1258. It causes my UTF-8 characters to fail showing a "?".